# Не запускается программа

Tags: c++, gdi

Пытаюсь нарисовать треугольник, но что то идет не так.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <graphics.h>

struct Pnt{
    int x,y;
};

class Trn{
    public:
        Pnt a,b,c;
        Trn(Pnt,Pnt,Pnt);
        void show();
};

Trn::Trn(Pnt A,Pnt B,Pnt C){
    a=A;
    b=B;
    c=C;
};

void Trn::show(){
    int Poly[8]={a.x,a.y,b.x,b.y,c.x,c.y};
    drawpoly(4,Poly);
};

int main(){

    int gd=DETECT,gm;
    initgraph(0,0,"");
    Pnt a,b,c;
    a.x=100;
    a.y=100;
    b.x=190;
    b.y=100;
    c.x=100;
    c.y=190;

    Trn trn1(a,b,c);
    trn1.show();
    system("PAUSE");
    closegraph();
};
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\prj1\main.cpp    In function 'int main()':
29  18  C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\prj1\main.cpp    [Warning] deprecated conversion from string constant to 'char*' [-Wwrite-strings]

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib\libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib/libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib\libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../..\libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib/libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../../lib/libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    skipping incompatible C:/Program Files (x86)/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/bin/../lib/gcc/x86_64-w64-mingw32/4.9.2/../../../libbgi.a when searching for -lbgi

C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw32\bin\ld.exe    cannot find -lbgi

C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\prj1\collect2.exe    [Error] ld returned 1 exit status

25      C:\Users\zxcvbnm\Documents\prj1\Makefile.win    recipe for target 'prj1.exe' failed
```

Comment: У вас же написано «cannot find -lbgi» — не может найти библиотеку. Вернее, библиотека есть, но она несовместима. Попробуйте скомпилировать с флагом `-m32` или выберите 32-битный режим в настройках.

Comment: Библиотека лежит в C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\lib
Заголовки в C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\include
Линкеру пробил -lbgi
-lgdi32
-lcomdlg32
-luuid
-loleaut32
-lole32

Ума не приложу, что ему не нравится..

Comment: В коде используется библиотека BGI от TurboC++ тридцатилетней давности для  MS DOS. Стоит подумать о более адекватных средствах для работы с графикой.

Comment: Ничего плохого нет в том, что такая программа не запускается...

Comment: Кстати, в `int poly[8]` только шесть элементов.

Comment: @DedBabay, можете попробовать по-переставлять местами ключи для линкера, возможно дело в порядке подключения библиотек.

Comment: [Error] ld returned 1 exit status - main у вас ничего не возвращает